# User taken to bottom of page on rotation

Tags: viewport, meta

I've come across an issue present on IPad and IPhone 6. When the user is at the middle of the page and rotates from landscape to portrait they are taken to the bottom of the page. After a lot of looking around into the issue I found that I could fix the issue using the viewport meta tags. I am currently using:

```
`<meta name="description" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1/>`
```

When I remove the initial scale the issue is fixed but then the ipad scaling issue occurs where landscape is zoomed in and portrait is not.
Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use **autoLayout** and **size classes** to set your View according to orientation you will not need to look for metadata detail.

Comment: @baydi do you want them to give all the IDEs they aren't using? It is pretty obvious they aren't using xcode since the code they have provide is html.